# Status code of 426 is returned instead of 200 when getting a simple endpoint from an Express app (in localhost) using Karate

Tags: express, karate

I have written a simple Express app. I am trying out Karate for API Testing, when I try to get a certain endpoint (literally GET) im expecting a response of status code 200 and the json test data for that endpoint. However, I am getting a 426 instead.

Here is  the karate feature file

```
Feature: Test 

  Background:
    * url 'http://localhost:3000'

  Scenario: Read users
    Given path 'users'
    And header Upgrade = 'HTTP/1.0'
    And header Connection = 'Upgrade'
    And header Accept = 'application/json'
    And header Accept-Encoding = 'gzip, deflate'
    And header Connection = 'keep-alive'
    When method get
    Then status 200


    * print response
    * print response.headers
```

I only have one dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.RC2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

The express app:

```
const port = 3000

    var testData = [
            {
              "name": "John Mayer",
              "info": {
               "title": "Mr.",
               "age": "35",
               "phone": "23423423-23423",
                "email": "jmayer@test.com"
            },
            "id":"old001"
        }
    ]
    
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`)
    })
    
    
    app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.protocol)
        res.status(200).send(testData)
    })
```

When I try this with Postman I get a 200 and the expected json test data.

I tried adding the Upgrade and Connection headers in the Karate feature too but I'm still getting a 426 status code.

Here is the screenshot of the response im getting.
[426 response and server:websocket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSVA5.png)

The 'Server: Websocket++/0.70' looks odd but I am unsure where that originates from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update/Solution :
Changing the port (from 3000 to 3500) solved it for me.

I was encountering the issue earlier whilst using a work machine with proxy/anti-virus which may explain why I was not getting the proper status codes as @PeterThomas has also pointed out. Changing the port solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First try removing all the headers in your Karate test.

If it still doesn't work, add back the `Accept` header.

Comment: Still got a 426 when removing all the headers and adding back the Accept header

Comment: @TheWanderer this was so surprising that I created an express project to check. it works fine for me: https://github.com/ptrthomas/karate-express-demo - so I have no idea what's going on at your end. maybe you have some weird proxy or anti-virus thing in your environment

Comment: Thanks for trying to solve this, I've tried my code and your code on a personal laptop and it both worked using the port 3000 . The work environment I had earlier is probably running an anti-virus causing the issue as you have pointed out.

Another solution that I came across , was to change the default port of 3000 to something else (ex. 3500) and that would make it work too.